# WISE Windows Installer Editor Launch Condition By date

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer, wise

I want to Prevent perform the installation if it exceeds a certain date, how can i do that?

any ideas are greatly appreciated. thanks!

(Note: Using Wise Installation Studio version 7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to do this effectively in MSI because it would be so easy to bypass it.  You'd be better served by either building a self-extracting EXE that does the date time check or moving the business logic into the application proper so that it stops working after a certain date time.

Comment: I agree - it is too easy to simply change the date for the install, then reset it to the actual date.  Having to set the date every time the app runs is more inconvenient. The only reliable solution is to connect to a server and get the date and see if it's too late.